# $G<GL_n(k), g \in G$, upper triangle, with diagonal elements as $1$. Show$Char(k)>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $k$ be a field, $n$ a positive integer and $G$ a finite subgroup of $GL_n(k)$ such that $|G| > 1.$
Further assume that every $g ∈ G$ is upper-triangular and all the diagonal entries of $g$ are $1$.

Show that char k > 0.

My attempt

the minimal polynomial divides $x^{|G|}-1$. Then the minimal polynomial divides
$$(x-1)(1+x+x^2 ...... x^{|G|-1})  $$

if $char(k)=0$ then can I show somehow that $g=I, \forall g \in G$?
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I'd take this approach: In $G$, we have an element $g$ such that $a:=g-1$ is nilpotent. The minimal polynomial of $a$ is of the form $X^m$ with some $m\in\Bbb N$. As we exclude the case $g=1$, we certainly have $m>1$.
As$g$ must have finite order, there exists an integer $r\ge 1$ with 
$$ 0=g^r-1=(1+a)^r-1=ra+{r\choose 2}a^2+\ldots +{r\choose m-1}a^{m-1}.$$
On the right we have a polynomial in $a$ of degree $<m$, hence by minimality, it must be the zero polynomial. As $m\ge2$, the sum is not just the empty sum, i.e., first summand $ra$ is really there, and we conclude that $r=0$ holds in $k$.

Comment: why does there exist such a nilpotent element?